# How do I handle HDR photos in Aperture 3?

Tags: software-recommendation, software, aperture, plugins, hdr

What **plugin** do you guys use to handle HDR photos in Aperture 3 ?

Comment: This may fare better on the photos site.    Not suggesting it's off-topic here, but I'd guess that the percent of photo enthusiasts using Aperture is way higher than the percent of mac users who do.

Comment: Jaydles... if you use Aperture, then you're a Mac User as Aperture only runs on mac :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two choices available right now:

- [Photomatix](http://www.hdrsoft.com/)
- [Hydra](http://www.creaceed.com/hydra/)

You should try both and see which matches your “taste” better :)

Answer (score 1):

Photomatix seems to be the most well-regarded.